# Y axis Header in Chart

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a chart as a user control in WPF. For the Y axis header I had added a textbox. It is displayed in the vertical direction. User can edit the title. While clicking on the textbox, it should be rendered in horizontal direction over the chart plot area. After user entered the text it should be in the default vertical direction.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rotate on focus styling your textboxes. Something like

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="-90"></RotateTransform>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="0"></RotateTransform>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

Comment: I am not able to accept. It shows vote up requires 15 reputations. Thats why only i didn't update.

Comment: I don't think you need a reputation level to accept the answer, just click on the tick below the vote up/down buttons.